# Converting a list of strings to a list of int for machine learning

Tags: python, machine-learning

I have a table with a column corresponding to the education level : `"phd", "undergrad"`, etc.

I would like to change those features to `0, 1, 2....`. in order to use the data as an input of a machine learning algorithm.

Is there a way in Python to automatically map those string features to integers?

Comment: You can also try more advanced things like word2vec, but the one-hot encoding will probably get you where you need to be. Just remember, you cannot have all of your variables in their own columns - a one-hot encoded dataset should always be len(categories)-1

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`enumerate`](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/enumerate.html) if you want to have the same serial order.

```
lista = [ "phd", "undergrad", "etc"]
>>> [i for i in enumerate(lista)]
[(0, 'phd'), (1, 'undergrad'), (2, 'etc')]
```

Comment: I think this can be used with a slight modification to convert it to a dictionary mapping the degree to an index like this: `dict([(degree, index) for (index, degree) in enumerate(lista)])`.

Comment: @suripoori, yes that's the idea behind it. unless you have the same order.  
 `{k:v for k, v in enumerate(lista)}`

Answer (score 1):

It's called a dict (dictionary).  Something like this:

```
edu_level = {
    "phd": 0;
    "master": 1;
    "undergrad":2, 
    ...
}
```

Look up how to work with dictionaries, perhaps using keys "Python dictionary tutorial".

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem is that there are way too much values to hard-code a dictionnary such as you did.

Answer (score 1):

You will likely not want to feed the data as it is to a machine learning algorithm - for instance, if a phd is a 2 and a masters is a 1, does that mean that the phd is twice as good? You might instead use "one hot encoding" and create a binary matrix (i.e. 1's & 0's) that you can feed.

There are multiple libraries to do this, i.e. one such: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html

Good luck!

> ```
>          BA MS PHD
> Person A  0  0  0
> Person B  1  0  0
> Person C  0  0  1
> ...
> ```

Comment: That is a good point. But even to do so, as there are many features and many values per feature, it would require hours of manual preprocessing.

Comment: pd.get_dummies() can do this very quickly - i.e. you can loop through your dataset, for each categorical, get dummies? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html

Comment: Ok that is exactly what I wanted. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just make sure you store them back in the dataframe as you go :)

Comment: Can you accept @thb ? Let me know if you have any other questions!